# HTTP ERROR 500 when return a view in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to custom `public function render($request, Exception $exception)` to catch all errors in laravel.
So, I did it like some code below

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return view('error');
}
```

When the page had errors I was received

> This page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Anyone know this, please help me.

UPDATE

The first: When I run my project, sometime I received some bugs like this:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

So, I want to hide this bug and some bugs from my project.
I searched and found the link [Laravel 5 handle all errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188652/laravel-5-handle-all-errors)

I followed that link and see some errors above.

Comment: Please post a full stack trace of the exception along with all applicable code.

Comment: Thank @btl I updated some info above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is due to using an incorrect HTTP verb to access a route, i.e. using `GET` when the route expects `POST`. Double check your route definition and what is being used to reach it, make sure they match up. Example:

```
Route::post('/user', 'Usercontroller@store');
```

and the client is using:

```
$.get('/user', {...data...});
```

This would not work and you would see the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Edit:

Solved by including:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpE‌​xception;
```

Comment: Thank @btl for help me. I know that, but I want that all the errors come from my project have to redirect to the page I want. In my project is error.blade.php page.

Comment: not yet. I can't control the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error, so I want to redirect it to the page I want. @btl

Comment: Ok to specifically look for `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` use `if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) { return view('error'); }` .

Comment: I did it before, but I received `This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` @btl

Comment: Did you include `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException;` at the top of your file?

Comment: `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException; 
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return view('error');
            }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }`. I did it like you support but I received `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` @btl

Comment: Oops that is the wrong exception, sorry. Use this: `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;`

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked perfectly. Thanks for your help @btl.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Toss an upvote and green check this way -.^